# Adding lib to config autoload paths does not autoload my module in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Adding lib to config autoload paths  does not autoload my module in Rails 3.

I add in my config/application.rb file.

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

In my controller I added

```
require 'lib_util' (or)
include LibUtil         #both doesn't work
```

In my lib/lib_util.rb file, I have the following module

```
module LibUtil
  module ClassMethods
    def p_key(a,b)
      //mycode            
    end
  end
    def self.included(receiver)
       receiver.extend ClassMethods
    end
end
```

I get the error undefined method `p_key'. The important thing to be noted is I ve called the same module in my model it works fine. But in my controller it does not identify the module.

Can anybody guide me??

Comment: try in your controller after for ex: `class PostsController` add `include LibUtil::ClassMethods`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try including both the modules ?

```
include LibUtil::ClassMethods
```